# Symfony Form Validation getters always triggering/failing

Tags: symfony

I'm using [Symfony's Validator Getter Component](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/book/validation.html#getters)  In conjunction with symfony forms.

In one of my entities files, I have:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class StudentPaper
{
   .....
   /**
    * @Assert\IsTrue(message = "You must include a paper with your submission")
    */
   public function hasPaper()
   {
       // I originally had logic that checked the validity, but just 
       // changed the return value to 'true' to prove that it's not working.
       return true;
   }
}
```

Unfortunately, the validation always fails (even when I hardcore the return value to be `true`).  The validation code doesn't seem to be executed, and the form triggers the error.  I even tried replacing it with `IsFalse` and hard coding `false`.  Same result.

Anyone come across this?

Symfony 2.8.
PHP 5.6.15

Comment: what are you doing to trigger the validation?  If is a from submit?  If so can you also post your form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I can't fully explain what the actual problem is (because I don't know), but I did find a solution.

In my StudentPaper entity I had

```
 /**
 * Bidirectional - Student Papers have one file.
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="StudentPaperFile", inversedBy="student_paper", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 * @ORM\JoinColumn()
 * @Assert\Valid()
 */
protected $paper;
```

as a property.  Turns out that having a property named `paper` AND a validation getter called `hasPaper()` was causing unexpected behavior.  As soon as I changed the function name from `hasPaper()` to `hasTesting()` or `hasSubmittedPaper`  then the getter worked as it was intended.

So the solution is that **the getter function cannot be get/is/has + a mapped property name.**

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution, I just hit the same issue - definitely needs documenting!